# Cannot get webviewer to work

Tags: java, android, webview

I want users of my app to click on an image, if they do so, a new activity must be loaded. This activity then shows a predetermined webpage. But when adding the webviewer widget, it doesn't work.

```
Activity name = activity_webbrowser_inno.xml
Actual webviewer widget name = webview_inno (in a constraint layout)
Java name = activity_webbrowser_inno
```

In the XML file:

```
    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview_inno"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

In the activity_webbrowser_inno.java file:

```
package eu.inno.inno
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class activity_webbrowser_inno extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webbrowser_inno);

    }
    WebView webview_inno = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_inno);
    webview_inno.loadUrl("http://www.inno.eu")
```

ERROR in red on the loadUrl. On hover: cannot resolve symbol 'loadUrl'.

I know there are other threads about this, but following their steps didn't seem to work. Or I couldn't understand them. This is my first project.

Comment: java's basics: method's call outside method body

Comment: It works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  private void uiBind() {
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new FileWebView());
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    if (mode == Constant.PDF_FILE) {
        webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
                + "http://www.5gamericas.org/files/2714/1471/2645/4G_Americas_Recommendations_on_5G_Requirements_and_Solutions_10_14_2014-FINALx.pdf");

    } else if (mode == Constant.DOC_FILE) {
        webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
                + "http://ijsetr.com/uploads/4256135G%20Mobile%20Wireless%20Technology.docx");

    } else if (mode == Constant.EXCEL_FILE) {
        webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
                + "http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/4/E/14EDED28-6C58-4055-A65C-23B4DA81C4DE/Financial%20Sample.xlsx");
    }
}

public class FileWebView extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to open a local pdf file thats stored in main/assets? Bonus: needs to open the file in english if global variable "taal" is set to "english". This english pdf file would be the same as the Dutch one, but with ENG added in the filename.